# Error: "data must only contain string values" firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send some data from my node.js server to an android client via FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging). I get the following error: "data must only contain string values" when sending it. My data contains 2 JSONObjects. Do I have to convert them to strings or what is the way to go here? Thanks.

```
var message = {
    notification:{
        "title": "Alert!",
        "body": position[0] + " has left Area: " + activeGeofences[i][1].name
      },
      data:{
        Geofence: activeGeofences[i][1],
        Position: position[1]
      },
    token: activeGeofences[i][0]
  };
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To convert any JSON objects to a string, you can use `JSON.stringify()`. On the receiving side you can then use `JSON.parse()` (or your platform's equivalent) to parse the string back into a tree structure.

Comment: Thanks, helped me alot. I did it like: 
    var geofenceAsString = JSON.stringify(activeGeofences[i][1]);
On serverside and: 
    String geofenceAsString = remoteMessage.getData().get("Geofence");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Geofence geofence = gson.fromJson(geofenceAsString, Geofence.class);
On Clientside

Comment: It's worth mentioning you can't just encode an object into a JSON string and assign that to the `data` property either. The `data` property must be an Object, non-null, and only have string properties. So you'd have to add a key for your JSON string like `{data: {enc: JSON.stringify(obj)}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this, since it seemed more accurate to me

```
data: {
       key1: "value1",
       key2: "value2",
        }
```

you just have to make sure that value1 or value2 or any n key's value pair is string if its a int or anything else it would throw the error. This could save you from parsing thing.

Answer (score 0):

Inside data object data type should be always strings.
If you will pass type a number data type an error will occur.

```js
let message = {
  notification: {
    title: payload.title,
    body: payload.message,
  },
  data: {
    name: 'sds',
    type: '2',
    _id: 'sdsd',
  },
  token: deviceToken,
};
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by giving the solution. I think you repeated the question instead of providing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone struggling with Python. Apparently it has to be an **Object containing only Strings**

```
body = json.dumps(data_object)
def send_notification(topic, title, body):
"""Send FCM notification to a specific topic"""
message = messaging.Message(
    topic=topic,
    data={"message": body},
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title=title,
        body=body
    )
)

# Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
response = messaging.send(message)
# Response is a message ID string.
print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```